# ReactiveUI CombineLatest not trigger Func

Tags: wpf, observable, reactiveui

I am using ReactiveUI in WPF. I bind one `ListBox.ItemSource` to my `ViewModel.FileList`.

The below `Observable.CombinedLatest()` doesn't trigger the Func.
But the above single Observable trigger its Func.

The reason I want to use combined observable is:
  I would like to display a list of data on the first time load - this is triggered by the ConvertedMessage property value changed.

Then I also need display different list when user enter the words on the search textbox, both of them actually update the same DataBinding Source List.

I also tried two different individual observables, two separate Methods in the `Observable.SelectMany(MyMethod)`, but seems the second observable override the previous one - because only the last `observable.MyMethod` called.

Is there any idea or suggestion regarding the ReactiveUI `CombinedLatest()`, is it only trigger the function when all observables produce the element?

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ConvertedMessage).Where(x=>x!=null).Subscribe(x => { var msg = x.Message; });

        var initial =
            this                
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.ConvertedMessage)
            .Where(x=>x!=null);

        var searchObjs =
            this
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchText)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800))
            .Select(term => term)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Where(term => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(term));

        reviewFiles = Observable.CombineLatest(initial, searchObjs, (message, term) => {
            ObservableCollection<PrecedentFile> loadedFiles = new ObservableCollection<PrecedentFile>();

            var start = 0;
            CurrentPage = 1;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
            {
                //some logic
                return searchedResults;
            }
            else
            {
                //other logic

                return loadedFiles.AsEnumerable<PrecedentFile>();
            }

        }).Select(x=>x)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.ReviewFiles);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you are facing is the `CombineLatest` needs all observables passed into it to have at least had event/signals occurred at least once.

In your example above if `initial` has a trigger but `searchObs` does not, then the `CombineLatest` won't fire.

Eg you've had the ConvertedMessage be changed 3 times, but SearchText has never been changed, then the CombineLatest will not fire.

One thing you could do is remove the `.Where(x => x != null)` and `Where(term => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))` statements and handle those conditions in your CombineLatest lambda. `WhenAnyValue()` will be default signal with the initial value of your properties (which is often null). That way both sides have already had a value signalled.

Comment: Another thing you can do for observables that may not fire right away is use `.StartsWith("")` to ensure that there is a value for combine latest to pickup.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, your suggestion is helpful, when I remove two where filers, and add the conditional handler in my codes below, it really triggered on either sources.